# Dealing with multithreaded output sequentially

Tags: python, multithreading

I've got some code that generates thousands of invoices as PDFs and then writes them to a zip file and then pumps that out over a HttpStreamingResponse (django). The PDF generation is *really* slow and currently single-threaded.

I can generate the source HTML for the PDFs quite fast. I would like to:

- Generate all the HTML (single threaded, database can't handle concurrent lookups)
- Convert these to PDFs, in 8 threads
- *Synchronously* handle the output of the PDFs so I can add it to my zipstream file.

I've dabbled with multiprocessing.Pool before but I've no idea how to do this properly. Here's some very approximate code.

```
def generate_statements(request):
    htmls = [generate_html(customer) for customer in customers]
    pdfs = [generate_pdf(html) for html in htmls]

    # create zip file

    for pdf in pdfs:
        zip.writestring(...)

    # output this to browser

def generate_html(customer):
    # do something that returns a string of HTML

def generate_pdf(html):
    # do something that creates a single pdf
```

If there's an option to start converting the HTML before the htmls are finished, even better, but I need to handle the output of `generate_pdf` in a linear way; I can't write to the zip concurrently.

<sub>(PS: I realise that some of these things might sound like homework, but please look at my network profile before you assume I'm a lazy student... I'm a lazy professional programmer thankyouverymuch)</sub>

Comment: I'd go with [threading](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/threading.html) and [queues](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/queue.html). I guess that the actual job of generating PDFs is made by an external program; if this is the case, I'd avoid [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html), as it adds unnecessary overhead.

Comment: "database can't handle concurrent lookups" - getting a better database might be a good start...

Answer (score 1):

This is way easier. The answer below reminded me of the multiprocessing Pool map method. This is an asynchronous map - just like the builtin map. It will join (that is - it won't return until all the asynch stuff is done), and you will get an ordered list of all the items.

```
htmls = [generate_html(customer) for customer in customers]
print "Htmls is:" , repr(htmls)
print "Starting map"
pdf_pool = Pool(5)
pdfs = pdf_pool.map(generate_pdf, htmls, 8)

print "Done map"
# zip stuff
for pdf in pdfs:
    print(pdf)
```

Comment: Could you expand on that a bit? I've seen "Queue" lots while Googing around for this but it seems to be used more as a source than an sink. I'd pass it in as an argument but how do I run through the queue in my synchronous code?

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep

# html list that has to convert to pdf
jobs = range(0,100000)

def create_pdf(html,zipstream):
    print 'starting job {}'.format(html)
    pdf = convert_html_to_pdf(html) # finished converting, returns location of the pdf
    try untill suceed: #implement something that checks lock on zipstream
        zipstream.write(pdf)
    sleep(2)
    print 'ended job {}'.format(html)
    #do whatever, followed by whatever requirement for this html.


pool = Pool(processes=8)
with ZipFile('pdfs.zip', 'w') as myzip:
    print pool.map(create_pdf,(jobs,myzip)) # jobs is list of job
    #... when done, 
    zipstream.close()
```

Comment: My create_pdf needs to write something that my synchronous code can deal with (write to a zip). That's the problem here.

Comment: It's not that I want to "mix" them, it's that I'm not really storing the PDFs on disk, my PDF generation returns them as a bytestring so I can squirt them straight into the zip.

Comment: i've edited the answer, see if that logic works with your requirements

Comment: (You're going to think I'm being deliberately awkward now but) zipstream can't handle concurrent writes, hence that has to be in sync code.

Comment: have you tried with `'a'` mode?: zipfile is not thread-safe? doh! couldn't you check if zipfile has lock and try untill succeed?